# ACS - Where to find Audit Logs

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, security, scom

I think i got the Audit Collection service working.

Where do I see the Audit Logs from my Managed Agents?

I looked in my Operations Manger Console: Monitoring - Microsoft Audit Collection Services - *

Where do I see the Logs?

Where are the logs Stored in the Database - in Which Table I do see the following tables: in Server\OPSMGRAC - Databases - OperationsManager - Tables:

```
dbo.dtCategory

dbo.dtConfig

dbo.dtMachine

dbo.dtPartition

dbo.dtSource

dbo.dtType
```

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of SCOM are you using? In my 2007 install, its a view not a table. Use adtServer.dvAll5 which contains only the first 5 event params, or adtServer.dvAll which has ALL params, but it slower.

Comment: Im Using SCOM2012R2. where do i Find `adtServer.dvAll5`? is it at the SQL-server or at the Operations Manager

Comment: its in the SQL-Database. Databases - OperationsManager - Views

Comment: Is there another way to look them up in Operations Manager?

Comment: Look up what exactly? The tables, views, or the data within? For data use SSRS. Have you reviewed the product doc? Search for "audit reports" at http://blogs.technet.com/b/fesiro/archive/2013/01/08/how-to-deploy-audit-collection-services-acs-in-scom-2012.aspx

Comment: im searching for the actual events, which the collector collects

Comment: IIRC, it does not collect anything by default. It only collects events which meet the filter criteria you define... Please review doc in order to ask better/more specific questions.